# How to set up the properties in matplotlib subplot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, subplot

I want to make subplots in matplotlib and set up different properties:
but I have an error  `'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'setp'`

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.axvline(x=654.31, linewidth=4, ls = '--', color = 'Gold' )

(markers, stemlines, baseline) = ax.stem(dfs.index, dfs.RTCM)
ax.setp(stemlines, linestyle="-", color="olive", linewidth=0.5 )
```

I can not find the way i can solve it.
I will appreciate any help.

Comment: That error needs to be taken literally: The command simply does not exist. It's `plt.setp` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the line format and color directly in the stem function

```
ax.stem(dfs.index, dfs.RTCM, linefmt='C4-', markerfmt='D')
```